# Spring MVC @RequestParam values not being extracted from URI as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am wondering how spring split each parameters of a http request.
By example i have this method definition :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchGet(ModelMap model,
    @RequestParam(value = "memberId", required = false) Integer memberId,
    @RequestParam(value = "member", required = false) String member) {...}
```

and i use this url :

```
/search.do?member=T&O=
```

i get member = T and not member =T&O=

The request params are limited to only memberId and member.
Can i configure spring for solving this problem ?

Answer (score 11):

Some characters in URLs have a special meaning. If they are supposed to be part of a value they need to be escaped.

If your value is T&O= then it needs to be changed to T%26O%3D

Answer (score 4):

`&` is used to seperate request parameters.
URL contain request param name and value in following format

> `http://host_port_and_url?name1=value1&name2=value2&so_on`

In your case

```
/search.do?member=T&O=
```

Name    ->    Value
member   ->   T
O     ->   (No value- Blank)
So you are getting correct values

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your controller code, your URL should have been

```
/search.do?memberId=T&member=
```

Then request parameter names will get mapped correctly.

If you wish to use same URL as mentioned in your question, change controller code to :

```
public String searchGet(ModelMap model,
@RequestParam(value = "O", required = false) Integer memberId,
@RequestParam(value = "member", required = false) String member) {...}
```